# Почему не выполняется выражение в цикле for?

Tags: c#

Составил программу, но не могу довести ее до ума. Она выдает в ответе то, что я присвоил p, отказываясь считать.
[image: Условие]

```
int N = 0;
double n;
double p = 156;
Console.WriteLine("Введите N");
string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
N = Convert.ToInt32(s1);
for (n = N; n <= 1; n++)
    p = (Math.Log(n)) / (Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(n, 5)), 4));
Console.WriteLine("Ответ:" + p);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: При любых `N > 1`, цикл выполняться не будет. Совсем.

Comment: потому что у вас куча ошибок. Первая из них - вы считаете от N до 1. Если вы вводите N больше единицы, то ваш цикл вообще не выполняется, и p сохраняет значение 156 (откуда 156 кстати?)

Comment: @DreamChild взял с неба, для эксперимента. А какие остальные?

Comment: Ваш вопрос, возможно, является дублем [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534301/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f)

Comment: @Zealint не вижу там вопроса.

Comment: @Zealint я так понимаю, вы местный ненавистник людей с простыми задачами, даже несмотря на то, что некоторые из них из-за всех сил пытаются понять эти элементарные для вас вещи, но без посторонней помощи у них это не получается. Почему нельзя просто промолчать? О каком юморе вы говорите? Довольно странно и грустно, если для вас это является юмором.

Comment: @Mars, вы даже не понимаете, что делает ваш код. Вообще. При этом, вы видимо хотите, чтобы кто-то разжевал вам ваш типовой расчет и положил в рот. Так не бывает. Задавайте **конкретные** вопросы по тому, что **именно** не получается сделать и получите нормальный развернутый ответ.

Comment: Наверно, человек не знает, что начальный индекс пишется под знаком суммы, а конечный - над ним. Тешу себя надеждой, что строение цикла for он знает)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Как работает цикл `for`?**

Оператор `for` определяет инициализатор начальных условий цикла, условие завершения цикла и действие, совершаемое после каждой итерации цикла:

```
for (инициализатор; условие; действие)
    тело цикла;
```

- *Инициализатор* выполняется один раз перед началом цикла и используется для инициализации счетчика цикла.
- Логическое *условие* проверяется перед первой и всеми последующими итерациями. Если условие принимает значение `true`, цикл выполняется. Как только условие принимает значение `false`, цикл завершается.
- После первой и последующих итераций цикла выполняется *действие*. Как правило этот раздел используетcя для увеличения счетчика цикла.

**Почему "программа отказывается считать"?**

Допустим, [image: N = 10]. Сначала происходит инициализация счетчика цикла [image: n] значением [image: N]. Получаем [image: n = 10]. Перед первой итерацией цикла проверяем, выполняется ли условие [image: n \le 1]. Думаю, очевидно, что утверждение [image: 10 \le 1] ложно. Поэтому тело цикла не выполняется ни разу.

**Что делать?**

Нам нужно найти сумму ряда. Выражение можно раскрыть следующим образом:

[image: S=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt[4]{n^5}}=\frac{\ln 1}{\sqrt[4]{1^5}}+\frac{\ln 2}{\sqrt[4]{2^5}}+...+\frac{\ln N}{\sqrt[4]{N^5}}.]

Переменная [image: n] изменяется в пределах от [image: 1] до [image: N]. Таким образом, следует сделать следующее:

- инициализировать счетчик цикла [image: n] значением [image: 1];
- после каждой итерации увеличивать значение счетчика на единицу;
- завершить вычисление, когда значение счетчика превысит [image: N].

Получаем:

```
for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
    тело цикла;
```

**Теперь все верно?**

Нет. В приведенном коде на каждой итерации цикла переменной `p` присваивается новое значение. Таким образом, после завершения цикла переменная `p` будет хранить значение последнего члена ряда, а не его сумму. Для подсчета суммы ряда следует инициализировать переменную `p` нулем, и на каждой итерации цикла суммировать `p` с текущим члена ряда. Получаем:

```
double p = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
    p += значение_члена_ряда;
```

**А теперь?**

И снова нет. Дальше — больше. Из школьного курса математики мы знаем, что

[image: \sqrt[4]{n^5}= ({n^5})^\frac{1}{4}=n^\frac{5}{4}],

но никак **не**

[image: \sqrt[4]{n^5}=(\sqrt{n^5})^4].

Поэтому:

```
double p = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
    p += Math.Log(n) / Math.Pow(n, 5.0 / 4.0);
```

Очень важно явно указывать принадлежность `5.0` и `4.0` к типу `double`:

```
double a = 5.0 / 4.0; // 1.25
double b = 5 / 4; // 1
```

Comment: Ого, достойный первый ответ!

Comment: @VladD Спасибо :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за такой раскрытый ответ!

Comment: Хороший пример того, как человек не стал читать нотации, тратя свои и чужие нервы, а просто помог. И не только автору вопроса. Учитесь, хейтеры.